# How to flush route cache in fortigate

Tags: ospf, fortigate, fortinet, route

Is there something like route cache on fortigate like in linux? 
How can i clear this cache?

I have some problems with OSPF, after adding or changing redistributed network. Foritgate show routes correctly but traffic from some hosts is going to wrong patch.

Comment: Which firmware version are you on?

Comment: Firmware is 5.6.4.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 4):

From the CLI you can issue the following command to restart the routing service.

```
exec router restart
```

To restart OSPF, you can use.

```
exec router clear ospf process
```

Answer (score 3):

This might be a little late, but since the question still pops up on the Google search, I thought I answer it.

The following command works in 6.2.7* and above, but does not show up as an argument when trying to auto complete:

```
diagnose ip rtcache flush
```

*I don't have a system with a lower FortiOS to test.

[Here is the corresponding Fortinet Community article.](https://community.fortinet.com/t5/FortiGate/Technical-Tip-How-to-clear-FortiGates-route-cache/ta-p/198873)